# Can 'those' be used as a substitute for 'ones'?

Tags: word-choice, articles

Is the following statement correct?

> We don't use TableA properties because they conflict with TableB those.

I think that it should be "TableB ones", while my friend says that "TableB ones" is incorrect, and that it should be "the TableB ones" or "TableB those".

Comment: We don't use *properties of* TableA because they conflict with *those of* TableB.

Answer (score 1):

*We don't use TableA properties because they conflict with TableB those.* - is incorrect.

> I think that it should be "TableB ones", while my friend says that
>   "TableB ones" is incorrect, and that it should be "the TableB ones" or
>   "TableB those".

We use **"ones"** as a pronoun to *'refer to objects mentioned previously.'* It is the plural of **"[one](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/one)"**. (See Pronoun):

- We don't use properties of TableA. Which *ones* don't we use? **(Which properties)**

**"Those"** is the plural of **"[That](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/those)"** (See Adjective and Pronoun)

When we say: *"Those of TableB"* we refer to properties. So it means *"Properties of TableB"*

The right way to say what you want is:

- We don't use properties of TableA because they conflict with those of TableB.

So it means: *We don't use properties that belong to TableA because they conflict with the properties that belong to TableB.*

P.s. I might rather use *"come into conflict with"*:

- We don't use properties of TableA because they come into conflict with those of TableB.